# Python second loop not detected

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, arcpy

I am using python and some arcpy modules (that I do not think are important for my question) to run a code containing three iterations (a loop with two smaller loops inside). My code looks like this:

```
file = r"C:Directory\File"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(file,fields)
A = range(1,270)
os.chdir ('C:\Directory')
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('Sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok = True)
for a in A:
tot = 0
result = 0
for row in cursor:
    if row.getValue('Firstfield') == a:
        tot = tot + row.getValue('secondfield')
        print (tot)
    for row in cursor:
        print row.getValue('GTYS_Branc')
        if row.getValue('GTYS_Branc') == a:
            result= result + row.getValue(Field1) * ((row.getValue(Field2))/tot )
    sheet1.write((branch-1),0,finalIIIprob)
    sheet1.write((a-1),1,result)
    book.save('Excel.xls')
```

The code works but does not give me the results I want. I noticed that the problem is that it practically ignores the second internal loop and every iteration of the first internal loop after the first one. What could the problem be?

Comment: The problem is that after you have iterated over your `cursor` entirely, as you do in your interior loop, there is nothing left to iterate over, so the outer loop terminates immediately the next time it tries to get the next row. It has already given up all the rows and is at the end.

Comment: Make the variable different in the two loops.  For example, the first loop `for row0 in cursor`, the second loop `for row1 in cursor`.

Comment: Ok thank you, I did it this way and now it iterates also inside. The problem is that now I receive an error message during the result calculation, in particoular at result = result + ... ( I modified the question to show this part more precisely) with a "TypeError: "'float' object is not callable" . What could it be?

Comment: Catch the exception and print everything out.  Probably you'll find that something there's a `row.getValue` that's a float.  In generally though, StackOverflow isn't the best way to debug your code.

Comment: I know and I apologize about this last question. Anyway coming back to the original question, I did as you suggested me, i.e. I introduced `for row0 ` in the first loop and `for row 1` in the second loop. Now the code does all the first loop and the second loop once, but after that it stops (i.e. for the following iterations of `a` it does nothing). I tried to delete row0 and row1 at the end of their iterations but this so far gave me only an error at the following iteration (NameError: row0 is not defined). I have no idea how to come out from this I am sorry.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it by insert the "cursor" line inside the loop, so every time I delete the row0 and row1 and recreate them at every  `a` loop iteration.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it.  As it stands though, I think this question should be closed or deleted because the answer won't be useful to anyone else.

Comment: It is highly recommended to use the the data access `da` cursors, which are significantly faster. More details on GIS SE: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/108807/8104

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you are iterating over values in an "array", but there is nothing in there but one number which is A, not all the numbers from 0 to A, what you need to do is use range function:
try for i in range(A):